# Sound by application controls

Tags: gnome, sound, software-recommendation, settings

Are there any easy GUI controls that I can get access to which will allow me to set specific sound levels on certain specified applications in Ubuntu GNOME 15.04, running GNOME Shell, and GNOME 3.14?

---

**OS Information:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pavucontrol`

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

[image]

---

Or start <kbd>Sound</kbd> via your Activities menu

[image]